# How to add label and fields for the Title band of Jasper Report using DynamicJasper?

Tags: dynamic-jasper

I want to add various labels in the Title band of Jasper Report using Dynamic Jasper API?

Comment: You need to post the codes that you have already tried out

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options. One option is to start with a template which has just various labels and parameters which you populate through your code. You can create your own parameters or use the $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("foo") which you sent to the fillReport method, i.e. maps.put("foo", "bar"). The detail band you populate with DynamicJasper.

Check also this link:
http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-add-header-andor-footer-to-a-report/